# Why are the email settings fields not showing, and how do I fix this?

Tags: emails, settings, mandrill

I'm trying to set up SMTP in Craft backend Settings > Email to get Mandrill working. But regardless of which protocol I choose, no settings fields are shown, and when I click save it just says "Couldn’t save email settings". It's the same in both Firefox and Chrome.

What could be the problem here, and how do I fix it?

Many thanks in advance and best regards.

/Monkey

Comment: Are there any related errors in craft/storage/runtime/logs ?

Comment: In your browser, are you seeing any assets not loading/errors?

Comment: @ Jeoren: I poked around in the log files but could not decipher anything that would help. But there might be something in there that I don't understand. Don't matter now though, see @ All: below. Thanks for trying to help! *bowing*

Comment: @ Matt: got some internal server error on .../js/email_settings.js?x=... Don't matter now though, see @ All: below. Thanks for trying to help! bowing

Comment: @ All:  Ended up reinstalling Craft CMS, and that fixed it. Now, I just have to get my plugin to install. <=)

Comment: Awesome. Must have been a file that didn't copy over 100%.

Comment: Had to create a temporary 'Test' plugin for the new install of Craft to wake up and show my real plugin in the backend > settings > plugins. All is ok now. :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey would you mind adding your solution as an official answer?

Comment: @Brad I've posted my brute force solution below, but I can not mark it as a solution until tomorrow. <=)

Answer (score 1):

Since I was short on time I ended up reinstalling Craft. Not exactly a minimum effort solution, but it fixed the backend > settings > email problem (and the updates page, that was not functioning properly as well). However, new install would not show my plugin in backend > settings > plugins. The solution to this, was to create a bare minimum test plugin (just copy pasted from https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up), after which both the test plugin and my real plugin showed up in backend. All seem ok now.